# Refresh using 2 modules

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have only 1 sheet(named:Report) , i am trying to run module1 & module 2 of VBA Macro on the same sheet from Python and write the result into two different data frames for comparision .. where in when i run the code both the dataframes are being updated with module1 data itself

```
    if os.path.exists(templatepath):

        xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(templatepath), ReadOnly=1)
        xl.Application.Run(templatename +"!Module1.Fetch_details",report1,ReportName_1,FY,FYMonth,MonthStarting)
        xl.Application.Run(templatename +"!Module2.Fetch_details1",report2,ReportName_2,FY,FYMonth,MonthStarting)
        xl.Application.Quit()


    df1=pd.read_excel(templatefolderpath+"Results\\"+ ReportName_1 + ".xls",'Report')
    df2=pd.read_excel(templatefolderpath+"Results\\"+ ReportName_2 + ".xls",'Report')
```

Comment: Please try to make your question clearer saying exactly want expect as output and the actual problem. [ask]

Comment: Don't put the information on the question, just 'edit' your question. It's not me who is going to be able to answer this question.